# What's the rule for bare infinitive in a dependent clause?

Tags: grammar, sentence-patterns, dependent-clause, bare-infinitive

I've been reading a chapter in a certain (programming) book and stumbled upon the following sentences (and I'm sure I've seen more examples like this in the book):

> - Since randomized tests are nondeterministic, it is critical that the log record sufficient information to reproduce the failure.
> - It’s important that code being tested not call (certain functions).

(While I would expect 'the log records' and 'code doesn't call'.)

The book is well-edited so I don't think all of these can be mistakes.

So what's the rule about using bare infinitive after 'that' (or probably in similar constructions)?

Comment: I wonder why you're asking about "bare infinitive"? Should it be "to infinitive"? You've said you would expect "the log records" and "code doesn't call". Your versions would simply be present indicative verb clauses. What you have in the examples is the present subjunctive mood, which is why there's no extra final 's' in "record" that you would normally find in third person singular present tense indicative conjugation. Also in the second case the subjunctive doesn't use "does" in negation. He does not go tomorrow - It's important that he not go tomorrow.

Comment: @Zebrafish The present subjunctive is morphologically identical to a bare infinitive (including negation without _do_-support), and some would claim that it’s not really possible to draw a line between the two, so the wording of the question does make sense.

Comment: A subjunctive clause is headed by a plain form verb, which is what "record" and "call" are.. Your non-subjunctive alternants are fine, and less formal than the subjunctives. Btw, why do you use the term 'relative clause' in your title? The subjunctive _that_ clauses  are declarative content clauses, not relative ones.